# If I change a domain name's name servers will all DNS entries be maintained?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm working with a domain registered with GoDaddy. The client has a WiX website so in GoDaddy they've set custom nameservers to point to ns4.wixdns.net etc. We're deploying a new website on a different server so I want to lower the TTL so I can point the DNS quickly when we get to go-live.

My question is this, if I change the nameservers in GoDaddy back to "Default" (presumably GoDaddy's own nameservers) will all the DNS records be maintained?

i.e. the current website won't become inaccessible due to the A record disappearing when I change the nameservers back to GoDaddy, right?

Comment: If you're deploying a new website, it will be using a new A record, e.g. newsite.example.com while the current website (WiX) lives at www.example.com? Then you just need to add the new A record with wixdns.net.

Comment: @Tom thank for the comment. No, the new site is replacing the other.

Comment: I changed the nameservers back and GoDaddy did in fact maintain the existing DNS records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they will not be automatically transferred over, and the website will become unavailable. You need to duplicate the records yourself before switching over.

Comment: Side note: Some providers will *attempt* to detect common subdomains and copy their values, but this is not foolproof and shouldn't be relied on.